# cloned aRGB images from imagelist object fidelity

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I note first that I'm working with VS 2010 Express.

My plan was to get cloned 32bppaRGB images, in this case 64x64, from an imagelist,  draw on them, and append them to the imagelist.
        I soon noticed that the clones, with no such drawing or
        any other changes made, appeared differently from the originals
when seen attached to items in the listview.  They appear
as if some alpha multiplication blending with some level of grey or who knows what color was done, but areas that are fully transparent are not affected.
But since this is object cloning, talk of anything happening in a graphics context should be nonsense.  Instead I am tempted to guess this is another
case of microslack.

[image: example]

the original on the left is color A190, 219,215,114

I guess my plan could be fulfilled by using ownerdraw, or compositing images with a graphics lib, but this issue seems really odd, and I'd like to know what's going on.

```
   to avoid that annoying issue with fading/greying images added via imagelists property page. 
   imageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.png0);//8 bit per channel aRGB
```

I tried pngs created with a few different tools ie ImageMagick, paint.net, GIMP.

the routine

```
    void foo {
        listView1.Items.Add("png0", 0);
        Image imgclone = (Image)imageList1.Images[0].Clone();
        imageList1.Images.Add(imgclone);
        listView1.Items.Add("png0clone", 1);
    }
```

Thanks